# Trying to figure out my exceptions handling C#. Any idea?

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. New to C#. For some reason when I enter a number in for input when the question is asked.. it just ends and says "exited with code 0". My exceptions handling DOES work but actually entering in the correct numbers doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

```
using System;

namespace MealInputLayton
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal mealOne = 0;
            decimal mealTwo = 0;
            decimal dessertOne = 0;
            decimal dessertTwo = 0;
            decimal subtotal = 0;
            const decimal TIP_PERCENTAGE = 0.2m;
            const decimal TAX_RATE = 0.07m;
            decimal total = 0;
            decimal numPeople = 2;
            decimal totalPerPerson = 0;
            decimal tip = 0;
            decimal tax = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("How much did your first meal cost?");
            try
            {
                mealOne = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (System.FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error for 1st meal price. Input string was not in a correct format.");

                Console.WriteLine("How much did your second meal cost?");
                try
                {
                    mealTwo = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error for 2nd meal price. Input string was not in a correct format.");

                    Console.WriteLine("How much did your first dessert cost?");
                    try
                    {
                        dessertOne = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch (System.FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error for 1st dessert price. Input string was not in a correct format.");

                        Console.WriteLine("How much did your second dessert cost?");
                        try
                        {
                            dessertTwo = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        catch (System.FormatException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error for 2nd dessert price. Input string was not in a correct format.");

                            subtotal = mealOne + mealTwo + dessertOne + dessertTwo;
                            tip = subtotal * TIP_PERCENTAGE;
                            tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;
                            total = subtotal + tax + tip;
                            totalPerPerson = total / numPeople;
                            Console.WriteLine("Subtotal: " + "$" + "{0:0.00}", subtotal);
                            Console.WriteLine("Tax: " + "$" + "{0:0.00}", tax);
                            Console.WriteLine("Tip: " + "$" + "{0:0.00}", tip);
                            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + "$" + "{0:0.00}", total);
                            Console.WriteLine("Per Person: " + "$" + "{0:0.00}", totalPerPerson);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you handling exceptions? Use `bool success = Decimal.TryParse("123.45", out decimal result);`. Also, encapsulate the request->return double pattern into a method, perhaps with a loop until the user inputs the correct data.

Comment: Application is reaching end of code and exiting.  Use Console.ReadLine() to stop application from ending.

Comment: Exit code 0 is "exited successfully", by the way.

Comment: You ask for the second meal only if the input for the first was incorrect.

Comment: Because all your execution logic is inside the catch block. you will get the second message printed if you gave the wrong input for the first.

Answer (score 1):

This answer summarizes what everyone mentioned in the comments - the best way to handle exceptions is to avoid them (which is a bit facetious - but true here).

Exceptions should be used for *exceptional* circumstances, and particularly when you need to *bubble* an error state up through a deep stack.  Users fat-fingering a number is hardly exceptional; it's something to be expected.

As @DiplomacyNotWar pointed it, it makes sense to push all the UI into a separate function.  That way, you can re-prompt if the user makes an error (again, that's something to be expected).  You could also put validation in there (for example, optionally specifying min and max values (I didn't do that).

So, here's a function that prompts users for a decimal value, and doesn't let them go further until they enter a valid number (if they really want to quit, they can press `<Ctrl>+C`)

```
private static decimal PromptForDecimal(string prompt, string? onError = null)
{
    if (onError == null)
    {
        onError = $"You must enter a valid decimal value: {prompt}";
    }

    Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
    while (true)
    {
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (decimal.TryParse(response, out decimal value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        //otherwise:
        Console.Write($"{onError}: ");
    }
}
```

Note that you can optionally have a separate prompt that shows up if there's an error.  Otherwise, you get a canned version based on the original prompt.  It's up to you what you want to do.

Also note that the `string? onError = null` parameter expression describes `onError` as a *Nullable String*.  You don't need the question mark if you aren't using *Nullable Reference Types*

With that in place, your code gets ***a whole lot*** simpler:

```
const decimal TIP_PERCENTAGE = 0.2m;
const decimal TAX_RATE = 0.07m;
decimal numPeople = 2.0m;

var mealOne = PromptForDecimal("How much did your first meal cost?");
var mealTwo = PromptForDecimal("How much did your second meal cost?");
var dessertOne = PromptForDecimal("How much did your first dessert cost?");
var dessertTwo = PromptForDecimal("How much did your second dessert cost?");

var subtotal = mealOne + mealTwo + dessertOne + dessertTwo;
var tip = subtotal * TIP_PERCENTAGE;
var tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;
var total = subtotal + tax + tip;
var totalPerPerson = total / numPeople;

Console.WriteLine($"Subtotal: {subtotal:0.00}");
Console.WriteLine($"Tax: {tax:0.00}");
Console.WriteLine($"Tip: {tip:0.00}");
Console.WriteLine($"Total: {total:0.00}");
Console.WriteLine($"Per Person: {totalPerPerson:0.00}");
```

Note that I removed all your variable declarations from the top, and put them where they are used.  It makes the code easier to read.  Don't worry, `var` in these declarations means `decimal` since `PromptForDecimal` returns a `decimal` value.

If you do want to pre-declare your variables, consider not initializing them.  If you had left all your declarations (of `mealOne`, `dessertTwo`, `tip`, etc.) uninitialized, and you tried to use them before they had values, the compiler would alert your.  If you forgot to use one of them, the editor would put a squiggly line under the variable name (try it out).

Finally, an expression like `$"Subtotal: {subtotal:0.00}"` is known as an *Interpolated String*.  They make your code easier to read.

Comment: I actually have to use exceptions. Its an assignment for school.

Comment: Get rid of the `TryParse` call and put a `try/catch` in instead